# How do I make it so the user is limited to only buy one of each item in my discord "shop"?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a economy discord bot which has a shop within it. I was having trouble to limit the user to only buy 1 item from the shop. This is because I have pets in the shop, and only want the user to be able the attain 1 within their inventory.

My existing code:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Founder")
async def adopt(ctx,item,amount = 1, member: discord.Member = None):
  if member is None:
    member = ctx.author

  await open_account(ctx.author)
  
 
  user = ctx.author
  
  res = await buy_pet(ctx.author,item,amount)

  if amount > 1:
    await ctx.send("You cannot buy more than one pet")


  elif not res[0]:
        if res[1]==1:
            await ctx.send("That pet is not in the shop!")
            return
        if res[1]==2:
            await ctx.send(f"**You don't have enough credits to adopt {item}")
            return
        if res[1]==3:
            await ctx.send("You already own this pet!")
```

Async def for buy_pet:

```py
async def buy_pet(user,item_name,amount):
    item_name = item_name.lower()
    name_ = None
    
    petshop = [{"name":"Hamster","price":5,"description":"dog",},
               {"name":"pheonix","price":50,"description":"cat",},
               {"name": "basilisk","price":50,"description":"basilisk"},
               {"name": "centaur","price":50,"description":"Centaur"},
               {"name": "pegasus","price":150,"description":"pegasus"},
               {"name": "BMO","price":500,"description":"BMO"},
               {"name": "plumfrog","price":500,"description":"plumfrog"},
               {"name": "drill","price":750,"description":"drill"},
               {"name": "elf","price":1000,"description":"elf"},
               
               ]
    
    

    for item in petshop:
        name = item["name"].lower()      
        
        
        

        if name == item_name:
            name_ = name
            price = item["price"]
            
            break

    if name_ == None:
        return [False,1]

    cost = price*amount

    users = await get_bank_data()

    bal = await update_bank(user)

    if bal[0]<cost:
        return [False,2]

    


    try:
        index = 0
        t = None
        for thing in users[str(user.id)]["bag"]:
            n = thing["item"]
            if n == item_name:
                old_amt = thing["amount"]
                new_amt = old_amt + amount
                users[str(user.id)]["bag"][index]["amount"] = new_amt
                t = 1
                break
            index+=1 
        if t == None:
            obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
            users[str(user.id)]["bag"].append(obj)
    except:
        obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
        users[str(user.id)]["bag"] = [obj]        

    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    await update_bank(user,cost*-1,"wallet")

    return [True,"Worked"]
```

So I basically want to make a new case within buy_pet, which makes it so the user can only buy one, and also make it so if they already have the pet, then they can't buy the same one again.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of database that keeps track of each member's properties.

Here is an example using a json file that you could use based on the way you've formatted your shop info:

```
{
  "member1": {
    "pets": [{name: "hamster"}, {name: "phoenix"}]
  }
}
```

Before you let the member purchase, you check their properties in the database and see if the pet exists in their 'pets' array. If it does, don't allow them to purchase, if it doesn't exist, let them purchase and add the entry to their 'pets' array.

Comment: I already have a json file to store the users info. It stores their money and items owned. I'm just not sure on how to refer to the amount within the file, while the user makes a purchase. @codecustard

Comment: What's your json file look like?

Comment: `{"331971067788787733": {"wallet": 12, "bank": 1, "bag": [{"item": "ticket", "amount": 1}, {"item": "dog", "amount": 5}, {"item": "cat", "amount": 0}, {"item": "drill", "amount": 2}, {"item": "plumfrog", "amount": 9}, {"item": "bmo", "amount": 4}]}, `

Do you think it would be easier if I made a separate json file for pets?, Because I have a different shop for items and pets @codecustard

Comment: How does your update_bank method look? It should be similar concept, but instead of looking at the bank, it would look at the bag.

Comment: Yes you probably could do that.... or maybe have an item property that tells you that the item is a pet... because it seems like you allow multiple non-pet items, but at the moment you can't distinquish between pets and non-pet items.

Comment: How would I add a item property for pets?

Comment: Something like:
{"331971067788787733": {"wallet": 12, "bank": 1, "bag": [{"item": "ticket", "type": "pet", amount": 1}]

But in your buy_pet() method, the key thing is the following:
`for thing in users[str(user.id)]["bag"]:
            n = thing["item"]
            if n == item_name:
                old_amt = thing["amount"]
                new_amt = old_amt + amount
                users[str(user.id)]["bag"][index]["amount"] = new_amt
                t = 1
                break
            index+=1`

It increments, but instead of incrementing, stop the transaction here.